# Expected value - introduction to probability

Tags: probability

You have 80 dollars and play the following game. An urn contains two white balls and two black balls. You draw the balls out one at a time without replacement until all the balls are gone. On each draw, you bet half of your present fortune that you will draw a white ball. What is your expected final fortune? Question is from Introduction to Probability by Snell.

Answer is 45. My fortune will be divided by 2 - exactly 2 times. What else can I infer from the information given in the answer?

Comment: There are only $\binom 42=6$ possible paths!  Just try each of them.  I expect you will see the pattern.  Note: I am assuming that each bet is at even payout.  That is, if you bet $X$ then either you lose $X$ or you win $X$.  If you meant something else, you should specify.

Comment: What is the return if you draw a white ball?

Comment: @copper.hat I have written the question as it is from the textbook. I suspect the return back is just my own money

Comment: If you divide $80$ by $2$ twice you have $20$, not $45$.  You need to account for the winnings when you draw a white ball.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably if you have $P$ dollars and draw a white ball you then have ${3 \over 2}P$ dollars, otherwise you have ${1 \over 2}P$ dollars.

Since you always draw all balls, you will encounter 2 white & 2 black balls and so will
**always** end with $({3 \over 2})^2 ({1 \over 2})^2 P$.

There is no need to compute an expectation here.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably when you draw a white ball you win the amount you bet.  Just try it.  If you draw BBWW you bet $40$ the first time and lose, bet $20$ the second time and lose, leaving $20$.  Then you bet $10$ the third time and win, giving $30$ and bet $15$ the last time and win, giving $45$.  There are five other orders of draws possible, all of which end with $45$.  You can see this because each black ball multiplies your bankroll by $\frac 12$ and each white multiplies it by $\frac 32$.  As multiplication is commutative, regardless of the order you will wind up with $(\frac 12)^2(\frac 32)^2=\frac 9{16}$ of your original bankroll